# Terminate Incoming Call Programmatically Android

Tags: android

I need to programmatically end an Incoming Call when a button from my App is being clicked.

If I use `TelephonyService`, it is working fine below 4.0 versions. But it is not working in 4.2.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) srvs
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c;
    final com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService;
    try {
        c = Class.forName("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");//telephony.getClass().getName());
        Log.i("TelephonyClass Name", telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (telephonyService.isIdle()
                            || telephonyService.isOffhook()
                            || telephonyService.isRinging())
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        long delay = Integer.parseInt(cutofftime) * 1000;
        new Timer().schedule(task, delay);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```